# Access-Control-Allow-Methods is not stopping POST call

Tags: cors, preflight

I made a simple web server on which I have set the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` allow only GET and OPTIONS methods.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer( function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.url, req.method)

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  
    if (req.url == '/foo' && req.method == 'POST') {
      res.write("post url is called")
    }

    res.end()
}).listen(8000);
```

From what I can understand from the [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/), any "non-simple" calls will cause the client to make a preflight request. The `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header which I have set on the `OPTIONS` response should prevent the client from making the request in case the method is not listed.

Here is a function that makes a POST call to the `localhost:8000/foo` and I've added a header to make it a "non-simple" request. I can see the preflight request being made from my browser but it doesn't stop the request though.

```
    async function postLogin(url, data) {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-some-header': ''
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      return response
    }
```

On changing the method from `POST` to `PUT` I can see it working as expected with this error on the console

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/foo' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

which is what I expected in the first example.

On further inspection of the spec, it says

> A CORS-safelisted method is a method that is `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`.

If that's case then why is preflight made in the first place for my `POST` call.

Answer (score 0):

It's being made to check the custom header. Try restricting the allowed headers here `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'not-x-some-header');`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not trying to block the request based on 'X-some-header', I'm adding the header to trigger the preflight request. The goal here is to block the POST request by using `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`.

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox blocks the POST request if `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` doesn't contain `POST`, Chrome seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/ specifications, when parsing a preflight response:

> If request’s method is not in [Access-Control-Allow-Methods] methods, request’s method is not a CORS-safelisted method, and request’s credentials mode is "include" or methods does not contain `*`, then return a network error.

It looks like a 'POST' request would always make it through because it's a CORS-safelisted method (`GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`).